# Jquery Parsing XML - Alternating Row Colour

Tags: jquery, xml, colors, row, alternating

How do I add code to the following to alternate the row color

```
parsedata = function(xml){        
            var str = "";
            var cart = xml.documentElement.firstChild;
            if(cart.childNodes.length > 0 ){                
                str = str + '<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
                str = str + '  <tr><td class="animBoxCartLink" colspan="2"><a href="' + globals.cart_link + '">' + globals.cart_text + '</a></td></tr>
                for (var i = 0; i < cart.childNodes.length; i++){               
                    try{name =  cart.getElementsByTagName("NAME")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){name = "Item";}
                    try{attributes =  cart.getElementsByTagName("ATTRIBUTES")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){attributes = "";}
                    try{llink =  cart.getElementsByTagName("LINK")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){llink = "";}
                    try{image =  cart.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){image = "No Image";}
                    try{qty =  cart.getElementsByTagName("QTY")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){qty = "message";}
                    try{price =  cart.getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}catch(e){price = "$0.00";}

                    dimension = (globals.cart_image_width ? 'width="' + globals.cart_image_width : '') + (globals.cart_image_height ? '" height="' + globals.cart_image_height + '"' : '');

                str = str + '  <tr>';
                str = str + '    <td class="animBoxCartImage" width="' + globals.cart_image_width + '" align="center"><a href="' + llink +'"><img src="' + image + '" ' + dimension + ' border="0" alt="' + name + '"></a></td>';
                str = str + '    <td class="animBoxCartContent" width="100%">';
                str = str + '      <div class="animBoxCartName"><a href="' + llink + '">' + name + '</a><br />' + attributes + '</div>';
                str = str + '      ' + globals.text_cart_quantity + ' ' + qty;
                str = str + '      <div class="animBoxCartPrice">' + price + '</a></div>';
                str = str + '      <a href="' + llink + '"> More Info </a>';
                str = str + '    </td>';
                str = str + '  </tr>';
```

The first half of the .js file (Jquery) pertains mostly to the show/hide of the cart which is located in the header and the portion I just posted is what I'm thinking is where I would need to add code where I can add styles so that the row color alternates.

Comment: still new here - not the whole script posted - which didnt come out to well :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the rest of your code the same:

Replace `str = str + '  <tr>';` with:

```
str = str + '  <tr class="rowcolor' + (i%2) + '">';
```

Then you need css classes defined for the rowcolors:

```
.rowcolor0 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.rowcolor1 {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff - whats happening now is I have 2 items in the cart - its only showing 1 item but the row color has changed for that one row - Yay am getting closer :))  just need the 2nd row also to show now :P

Comment: adding a third item caused an unresponsive script

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see that you already defined `i` as your loop iterator.  This would reset `i` and you would start all over, hanging your script.  I fixed my example above.  Just use (i%2) in your `tr` definition.

Comment: You are an absolute STAR - it's working like a dream - you've no idea how greatful I am - thank you sooo much :) x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even going to try to fix this. On the `tr`:

```
str += '  <tr>';
```

add alt row class:

```
str += '  <tr class="' + i%2 == 0 ? 'altrow' : '' + '">';
```